find-if-array-can-be-divided-into-two-subsets-of-equal-sum-if-any-one-element-deleted
Given a array of numbers find if there is a way to delete/remove a number from the array and make one partition in the array( dividing the array into two subsets ) such that sum of elements in subset1is equal to sum of elements in subset2.
For example - [1,2,3,4,5] if we delete 1 then sum(2,5)==sum(3,4) return true;
I approached it in TC: O(N * N * target), SC: O( target) where target can go up to sum(nums) / 2. We can try iterating the array and deleting each element one by one and if remaining sum is even then find out if any subset is there with sum equal remaining sum/2. there we can use dp.
Something like this... Can we do better than this?
for 0 -> n
    remaining = (total - nums[i])
    if remaining is odd number
        continue, not possible to split into two equal halfs
    nums[i] = 0      // remove element
    if can_partition(nums, remaining / 2)      // use dp to find subset sum equals k
         return true
    nums[i] = total - remaining    // if not possible, assign back

return false


You-forgot-to-post-your-attempt-to-solve-this-problem.

Updated!! @ScottHunter

In what way does this not solve your problem?

Can we do better than this?

"Better" in what way?  What have you tried?

better in terms of Time Complexity

Why do you think a solution is possible with a better one?

That's why I have posted this question here, that whether it possible to optimise more or not.

Assuming can_partition is optimal, I wouldn't think so.
